# How can i know cell frame over the main view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one `UIViewController` where i put `UITableView`.

Is it possible to get frame size of `UITableviewCell` over the `UIView` on DidSelect event ??
Because I want to create one Label with the same size of selected cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `convertRect` methods to switch between different coordinate systems.

To get the frame of view A, call this `cell`, in the coordinate system of view B, call this `view`, use the following:

```
CGRect cellFrame = [view convertRect:cell.bounds fromView:cell];
```

This will give you the position and size of the cell inside `view`.